# Arc length in spherical triangle

Tags: spherical-geometry

A spherical triangle has angles of 120◦, 60◦ and 45◦. Find the cosines of the (arc) lengths of the sides. How many sides have an arc length larger than 90◦?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the law of cosines, the one with the addition. If cosine is negative, it indicates that there is an obtuse angle which means the arc length will be larger than 90 in the number of angles.

Comment: ok. so i only found one value where cosine is negative so i'm guessing it means one side only

Comment: yes, so one side then if your calculation holds up